# How to automatically add a new name to cloned radio buttons in a new card

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

So currently i have a card which has some radio buttons with the name="radio-0" i want when i clone the card that all the radio buttons to change to name="radio-1" for exapmle

I have made a function that get the last child from the element being but it isn't working and only works one time.

My fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/abdotamer3/s57jauxw/22/

My function:

```
function nameRadioButtons(clone, radioButtons) {
    var allQuestions = clone.querySelector(".radioItemToggle:last-child");
    var radioID = allQuestions.getAttribute("name").split("-")[1];
    console.log(radioID)
    radioButtons.forEach((element, index) => {
        radioID =+ 1
        element.setAttribute("name", "radio-" + radioID.toString());
    });
}
```

My cloning function:

```
function cloneQuestion() {
    var question = document.querySelector(".questions");
    var clone = $(question).clone(true, true).get(0);
    var numItems = $(".questions").closest(".radioListItemPrimaryContent").length;
    var radioButtons = question.querySelectorAll(".radioItemToggle");
    console.log(numItems);
    nameRadioButtons(clone, radioButtons);
    clone.querySelector(".questionMainTextArea").value = "Untitled Question";
    var addBtn = document.querySelector(".addQuestionBtnRow");
    var tbody = addBtn.parentNode;
    tbody.insertBefore(clone, addBtn);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a global variable to store the currently maximum question index, and add 1 to it every time before setting the new name.

```
let radioGroupIndex = 0
function nameRadioButtons(clone) {
    radioGroupIndex++
    clone.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]').forEach(_radio => {
        _radio.setAttribute('name', `radio-${radioGroupIndex}`)
    })
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/suvfg1o9